# AWK how to process multiple files and comparing them IN CONTROL FILE! (not command line one-liner)

Tags: linux, database, awk

I read all of answers for similar problems but they are not working for me because my files are not uniformal, they contain several control headers and in such case is safer to create script than one-liner and all the answers focused on one-liners. In theory one-liners commands should be convertible to script but I am struggling to achieve:

1. printing the control headers
2. print only the records started with 16 in <file 1> where value of column 2 NOT EXISTS in column 2 of the <file 2>

I end up with this:

```
BEGIN {
FS="\x01";
OFS="\x01";
RS="\x02\n";
ORS="\x02\n";

file1=ARGV[1];
file2=ARGV[2];
count=0;
}

/^#/ {
    print;
    count++;
}
# reset counters after control headers
NR=1;
FNR=1;
# Below gives syntax error
/^16/ AND NR==FNR {
    a[$2];next;  'FNR==1 || !$2 in a' file1 file2
    }

END {
}
```

Googling only gives me results for command line processing and documentation is also silent in that regard. Does it mean it cannot be done?

Comment: consider reviewing [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular, provide sample input files, the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) expected output

Comment: `they are not working` - please provide examples of input and of actual errors (although it is obvious that the part after `next` makes no sense - how will it ever be reached? and it is not syntactically valid anyway)

Comment: Only GNU awk supports multi character `RS` [See docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/awk.html) Unless you are running on GNU awk, note **If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified.**

Comment: Note that in `/^16/ AND NR==FNR`  the `AND` will be treated as *variable name* so you are actually asking to concatenate `/^16/` with value which is hold in `AND` variable with result of test if it is first file. If you need logical and in AWK you should use `&&`, if you need logical or in AWK you should use `||`, if you need logical not in AWK you should use `!` (observe similarity with JavaScript). In case of multi-level statement it is wise to use `(` and `)` for showing order, rather than relying on operators precedence ("stickyness"), especially if anyone else will read your code.

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to tag `[database]` which you have used

Comment: daweo seriously? hashtag is most important to you? if you process rows of data then by definition it's database. Also I need this before I import stuff into MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try:

**script.awk**:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "\x01"
    ORS = RS = "\x02\n"
}

NR==FNR {
    if (/^16/) a[$2]
    next
}

/^16/ && !($2 in a) || /^#/
```

Note the parentheses: `!$2 in a` would be parsed as `(!$2) in a`

Invoke with:

```
awk -f script.awk FILE2 FILE1
```

Note order of FILE1 / FILE2 is reversed; FILE2 must be read first to pre-populate the lookup table.

Comment: Intresting, inside your script there is none reference to argv[1] and argv[2] hmmm

Comment: You don't need to refer to the names of the files inside the script. If `NR==FNR` you are reading the first file, otherwise you are reading the second one.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, short answer to my question should be "NOT POSSIBLE", if anyone read question carefully and knew AWK in full that is obvious answer, I wish I knew it sooner instead of wasting few days trying to write script.
Also, there is no such thing as minimal reproducible example (this was always constant pain on TeX groups) - I need full example working, if it works on 1 row there is no guarantee if it works on 2 rows and my number of rows is ~ 127 mln.

If you read code carefully than you would know what is not working - I put in comment section what is giving syntax error. Anyway, as @Daweo suggested there is no way to use logic operator in pattern section. So because we don't need printing in first file the whole trick is to do conditional in second brackets:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{} NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a) { if (/^16/) print $0} ' set1.txt set2.txt
```

assuming in above example that separator is comma. I don't know where assumption about multiple RS support only in gnu awk came from. On MacOS BSD awk it works exactly the same, but in fact `RS="\x02\n"` is single separator not two separators.

Comment: Some awks support multiple characters in RS but it is not portable: [If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

Comment: It is easy to use logic operators in patterns but you have to use the correct form: `&&` instead of `AND`, for example.